# Not able to calculate exact value for constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I'm calculating trailing constraints for stack view which is inside table view. It seems that calculation doesn't give exact value. Please refer to screenshot below. Is my calculation/logic incorrect? How to fix this so that I can get exact value?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCellID", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Can't find cell")
    }

    let profile = array[indexPath.row]

    if profile.isDisabled1 || profile.isDisabled2 || profile.isDisabled3 {

        let totalHiddenViews: Int = (profile.isDisabled1 ? 1 : 0) + (profile.isDisabled2 ? 1 : 0) + (profile.isDisabled3 ? 1 : 0)

        let singleViewWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32)/3 // 32 is sum of leading and trailing constraints

        cell.stackViewTrailing.constant = CGFloat(totalHiddenViews) * (singleViewWidth + 8)

    } else {
        cell.stackViewTrailing.constant = 8
    }

    cell.view1.isHidden = profile.isDisabled1
    cell.view2.isHidden = profile.isDisabled2
    cell.view3.isHidden = profile.isDisabled3

    return cell
}
```

[image: Scraanshot]

Comment: Maybe `UICollectionView` inside each table view cell would be the way

Comment: @RobertDresler, why don't just create one `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView`?

Comment: @user28434 right, with multiple sections

Comment: I'm already using stack view inside cell view which contains these three views. How UICollectionView will be better option than Stack view?

Comment: I've already used table view in my app and it's live and contains many fields inside the cell. Changing it to collection view will be complex for me. IS there anyway we can fix this in table view?

Comment: I think you forgot the spacing in your calculation. You always have n-1 spacing for n views.

Answer (score 1):

You also have issues with the [2-cell layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuW9u.png). My instincts say that one of your magic numbers is incorrect and the one I see here that is directly contingent on the number of visible cells is this line.

```
cell.stackViewTrailing.constant = CGFloat(totalHiddenViews) * (singleViewWidth + 8)
```

I would start by checking the sanity of that constant and work back from there starting with code that depends on the number of visible cells.

Comment: 8 is spacing between views inside the stackview and also the leading& trailing constraints between views and superviews.